# Burnt SMD diode identification. General Semiconductor S4 6CA

Tags: diodes, identification, surface-mount, schottky

I have an Artesyn 7001138-Y000 835 server power supply unit that has a burnt component. The burnt component reads S4 6CA and has the general Semiconductor logo on it. I have been looking online to find the specifications so I can replace it, but I have been unsuccessful. If anyone can help me out so I can get this running again that would be awesome!

[image: Smoked SMD diode with marking S4 6CA]

Comment: I think your problem is rather _why_ it burnt. Diodes just don't burn unless something happen to them.

Comment: I got it from a flying buddy. He was converting it to use as a power supply for his lipo charger. He was trying to install a 1k resistor between pins 17 & 19 to boost the voltage and I reckon he shorted something. The burnt diode was the only damage I could find to the board.

Comment: That S4 answer also helped me thanks, the S4 I found was a much smaller package and could not find the correct one so used a B260A -13-F Farnell 1843682 SMA package.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vishay/General semiconductor SS14.
It's a 40 volt schottky diode.

[Link to datasheet](http://www.vishay.com/docs/88746/ss12.pdf)

[image: Screenshot of datasheet]

The other digits refer to line and date. See here:
[Vishay markings](http://www.vishay.com/docs/88912/diodesgroupbodymarking.pdf)

Comment: Awesome!! I'd been looking for on the Vishay site but this datasheet had eluded me.

Comment: @Maarten. Glad to help. Remember to mark it as answered when you feel that your original question has been just that.